# can't open pom.xml and application.properties in eclipse

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I create a simple login program,
but when I tried to open application.properties to initialize the data base it won't,
and I found this error
"An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.IEclipseContext.activate()" because the return value of "org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.MPart.getContext()" is nullé

I installed some snapshots files but it doesn't work
and also I tried to write into the file directly from the notepad but also not working

this is the result when I try to open it [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHYpd.png)

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was too facing similar issue. Closing and opening the Eclipse again resolved my issue. My Eclipse version was

Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0)
Build id: 20220908-1902

Probably, try restarting the Eclipse by closing all the processes and applications related to Eclipse.

This was my error:
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.IEclipseContext.activate()" because the return value of "org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.MPart.getContext()" is null